# How do I prevent Google Chrome Developer Tools from resizing the browser viewport?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

Basically, I want Chrome Webtools to overlap my browser viewport instead of resizing it.

I tried undocking the tools window, however this splits it into another window which is undesirable. I want both the console and the viewport in the same window, just overlapping.

#### Current behavior:

[image: current]

#### Desired behavior:

[image: desired]

Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's not possible. Usually, I dock it aside but it's not the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to Dock Side from the three Dots at the side of console and ... have to manually frame it to the location you want

Answer (score -1):

[image: Devtools's menu]

You can click here and select `Undock to seperate windows`.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, that splits the devtools into a new window which I don't want. Ultimately, I want both the console and the viewport in the same window.